# neo4j cypher index query

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I was used to use node_auto_index( condition ) to search for nodes using indexes, but now i used batch-import ( https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/ ) and it created indexes with specific names ( type, code, etc ).
So, how to do a cypher query using indexes on multiple properties ?

old query example :

```
START n = node : node_auto_index( 'type: NODE_TYPE AND code: NODE_CODE' ) RETURN n;
```

how to do the 'same' query but without node_auto_index and specific index names ?

```
START n = node : type( "type = NODE_TYPE" ) RETURN n;
```

Also, the next query does not work (no errors, but the result is empty and it shouldn't be) :

```
START n = node : type( 'type: NODE_TYPE AND code: NODE_CODE' ) RETURN n;
```

So, type is an index, code is an index. how to mix the two in the same query for a single node ?

Another question: whats the difference of node_auto_index and this indexes with specific names ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
START n = node:type("type:NODE_TYPE") RETURN n;
```

or

```
START n = node:type(type="NODE_TYPE") RETURN n;
```

Comment: sorry, you didnt understand my question: how do i use multiple indexes in the same query?

Comment: put a comma between, `start n=node:type(...), m=node:other(...)`

Comment: but that is for 2 different nodes. i want to 'get' a node by 2 or more properties, using indexes

Comment: The way  you do it in your first example is right--just put in your index name instead of the node_auto_index

Comment: you can't mix two indexes in the same index query, unfortunately. However, you can add multiple fields to the same index.